# iOS background execution for health care apps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to implement the following requirement:

**iOS app should periodically(Ex:- Every 1 hour) collect the data from health app and send the data to the server when in background mode.**

I tried implementing this scenario like below :

I implemented the following code:-

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

```
    self.bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTaskWithName("updateMedicalData") {
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()

    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)) {
        print("Time remaining ::",application.backgroundTimeRemaining)
       NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(25, target:self, selector:#selector(self.performBackgroundTask), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
    }


}
```

I have implemented the logic of fetching the data from health app and sending server in the method "performBackgroundTask()"

But the issue is, App is running in the background only for 3 min and expiration handler is called.

I have set the key "Required background modes" to "App downloads content from the network" and for the key "Application does not run in background" to "NO" in plist file.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to implement the above requirement ?

Comment: You might be better off observing when data is updated and then sending that data to your server instead of checking every hour.  HKObserverQuery will let u do that

Comment: Have you achieved this? Is this possible? Please help me.Any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible for certain types of Apps to have longer background execution. More specific:

```
For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:

Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
Apps that record audio content while in the background
Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Please look at this link to see whether this will works for you. I guess that the "Background fetch" might suit your needs. In that case, you need to set your UIBackgroundModes value to "fetch". Did you already do this?

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Robski18 has answered. There's no way you can periodically send data to the server. The only way to do this is for the server to periodically send your app a silent push notification and have the background mode which is called in that answer "Apps that need to download and process new content regularly". Except you will be pushing content not fetching it.

Even if the server sends the push periodically that does not mean the app will receive them periodically, if the server sends them every hour the app might not receive one for several hours and then they'd be all bunched together.

Also if the user kills the app then the app will not receive the pushes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [BGTaskScheduler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler) is what can do the job. Though if your device is bluetooth based, there is special background mode for it when your bt device can wake up the app.